# What data type to use when storing PBKDF2 encrypted passwords?

Tags: .net, database, cryptography

I am using SimpleCrypto.Net to encrypt my passwords, which i understands uses PBKDF2 and a specified salt and number of iterations. I would like to know what's the most appropriate data type for me to set the password column to in the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From looking at the code the result is a base64 encoded key of 64 bytes. Considering base64 is made up of ASCII characters I would recommend storing it as `CHAR(88)` or to be on the safe side you could go with `VARCHAR(MAX)`. However, as the key size is fixed at 64 bytes the length of the result should never change (even if your salt/iterations are changed).

Comment: Thanks, exactly the kind of answer that I was looking for.