# Save byte array in sql server

Tags: sql-server, arrays, sqlcommand

Am looking to use an approach in saving passwords that requires using byte array as in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329909/hashing-passwords-with-md5-or-sha-256-c-sharp)

So which data type should i use in sql server to save byte array? and how can i pass and retrieve the byte array using SqlCommand?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If it's always going to be the same length, then `binary(length)` would be suitable. If it's going to vary in length, use `varbinary(maxlength)`.

[binary and varbinary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188362.aspx).

And, as @p.s.w.g says, you pass it from code by placing it into a suitable parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Really helped me a lot. I got confused at the beginning and think is important to remark that varbinary(maxlength) doesn't refer to varbinary(max). 'maxlength' refers to the maximum posible length for your hashed passwords

Answer (score 6):

Just use a `byte[]` the same way you would any other parameter, specifying `SqlDbType.Binary` as the parameter type. Here a sample in C#

```
// Generate your password hash some way
byte[] passwordHash = new byte[] { 0x0, 0x1, 0x2 ... };

...

command.Parameters.Add("@passwordHash", SqlDbType.Binary);
command.Parameters["@passwordHash"].Value = passwordHash;
```

Or if you prefer VB.NET

```
' Generate your password hash some way
Dim passwordHash As Byte() = New Byte() { &H0, &H1, &H2 ... }

...

command.Parameters.Add("@passwordHash", SqlDbType.Binary)
command.Parameters("@passwordHash").Value = passwordHash
```

Comment: is it fine to use binary sql data type? as i googled some people telling its use for big binary files like images, do you agree with that?

Comment: @user2155873 Use `VARBINARY(MAX)` for files which are somewhat large or are of varying length. For password hashes use `BINARY(32)` (or however long your hash is).

Comment: @user2155873 - given that you can declare a `binary(5)`, that allocates storage for 5 bytes, would you say that that was only suitable for storing a big file?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using `nvarchar(45)` and Base64 your 32 bytes into a string. This is the standard way of saving a hash.

Alternatively you could do `nvarchar(64)` and store it as a hex string.

Comment: I've read the Microsoft docs about this subject and never saw the recommendation to convert the hash to Base64. Anyway, why not saving the hash as a byte array?