# How to convert image to base64string Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, image, xamarin, xamarin.forms, blob

I want to convert my image to **base64string**. I want to save the **base64string** to my database. I can get the **path** of my image. How can I get the image from my path and convert the image to **base64string** and what **datatype** do I need to put inorder to save **base64string** to my database is it **BLOB**?

```
try
{
   var cafNo = entCafNo.Text;
   var time = tpTime.Time;

   await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

   if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
   {
      await DisplayAlert("No Camera", "No Camera Available", "Ok");
      return;
   }

   var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(
   new StoreCameraMediaOptions
   {
      SaveToAlbum = true,
      Name = cafNo + "_IMG_01.jpg"
   }
   );

   // provide read access to the file
   FileStream fs = new FileStream(file.Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
   // Create a byte array of file stream length
   byte[] ImageData = new byte[fs.Length];
   //Read block of bytes from stream into the byte array
   fs.Read(ImageData, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
   //Close the File Stream
   fs.Close();
   string _base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(ImageData);

   entPhoto1Url.Text = _base64String;
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
      await DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "OK");
   }
```

Comment: what is wrong with the code you have?  You appear to be reading the image from the file path and encoding it as base64.  Is it giving you an error or exception?

Comment: @Jason no, but the result of _base64String is the file path converted to base64string for example the file path is F:/Images/Image.jpg and the base64string is QSR/QWRE/WAASDAWASR it converted the whole filepath to base64string I want to get the image only

Comment: @Jason and what data type do I need to save the base64string?

Comment: "what data type do I save a string"

Comment: That is useful information that should have been in your original post.  Try using File.ReadAllBytes(path) to read the image data from disk.  You could either save it as a varchar or a blob

Comment: @Jason can you show me your code based on my code?

Comment: byte[] ImageData = File.ReadAllBytes(file.Path);  Get rid of all the FileStream stuff.    Read the MS docs on File.ReadAllBytes()

Comment: @Jason is it ok that the whole file path is converted to base64string?

Comment: @Jason is the file path that is being converted or the image only?

Comment: No.  First, confirm that ImageData really contains the image data and not the file path.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64string

Comment: @Jason ImageData contains **{byte[2693907]}**

Comment: @Jason just to clarify the data being converted to base64string is the image not the file path of the image?

Comment: Read the docs, they explain what the method parms are

Comment: @Jason is it ok that the converted base64 string is more than 500 characters long? How can I save that to my database?

Comment: Why would that matter?  Your image is 2.7M, encoding it will just make it larger

Comment: @Jason Is there a way to save the captured image to my server? other that converting it to base64 string? I am converting the image to base64 string and send it to my PHP api that will be saved to my mysql database

Comment: you can upload a byte array, you don't have to encode it

Comment: @Jason what data type do I need in order to save the byte array to database?

Comment: first result from google: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518051/save-byte-array-in-sql-server

Comment: @Jason is there another way for me to get the captured image and send it to my PHP API(Server)

Comment: @Jason please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51940340/send-byte-array-from-xamarin-forms-to-php