# Python Invalid parameter type when trying to execute insert query

Tags: python, sql, x509certificate

I'm trying to execute this query however I'm getting the error and I'm using Microsoft SQL Server as database.

```
import urllib.request as urllib
import socket
import pyodbc
from datetime import datetime
import ssl
import OpenSSL
import re


#Timestamp for undersøgelse
timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')



#Responseheader request
request = urllib.Request('http://ucn.dk')
request.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36')
response = urllib.urlopen(request)
rdata = response.info()
ipaddr = socket.gethostbyname(request.origin_req_host)


def get_certificate(host, port=443):
    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    conn = socket.create_connection((host, port))
    sock = context.wrap_socket(conn, server_hostname=host)
    der_cert = sock.getpeercert(True)
    sock.close()
    return ssl.DER_cert_to_PEM_cert(der_cert)


certificate = get_certificate(request.origin_req_host)
x509 = OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, certificate)
Pubkeyobj = x509.get_pubkey()
pubKeyString = OpenSSL.crypto.dump_publickey(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, Pubkeyobj)
pubkey = b'\n'.join(pubKeyString.splitlines()[1:-1])
keylength = Pubkeyobj.bits()
certvalidfrom = datetime.strptime(x509.get_notBefore().decode('ascii'), '%Y%m%d%H%M%SZ')
certvalidtill = datetime.strptime(x509.get_notAfter().decode('ascii'), '%Y%m%d%H%M%SZ')
extensions = (x509.get_extension(i) for i in range(x509.get_extension_count()))
extension_data = {e.get_short_name(): str(e) for e in extensions}


subj = x509.get_subject()
subjCN = x509.get_subject().CN
subjAlt = extension_data[b'subjectAltName']
serial = x509.get_serial_number()
issuerCN = x509.get_issuer().CN
sign = x509.get_signature_algorithm()





#SQL Connection til local database
con = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};'
                      'Server=DESKTOP-THV2IDL;'
                      'Database=host;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cursor = con.cursor()


con.execute('INSERT INTO host.dbo.certificate (host, Subject, CommonName, AlternativeNames, PublicKey, KeyLength(BITS), SerialNumber, Validfrom, Validtill, Issuer(CN), CSA, Timestamp) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', 
           (request.full_url, subj, subjCN, subjAlt, pubkey, keylength, serial, certvalidfrom, certvalidtill, issuerCN, sign, timestamp))

con.commit()
```

I get this error:

> File "c:/Users/Farzad/Desktop/Python/Webscraping/Responseheaderinfo.py", line 76, in 
>   (request.full_url, subj, subjCN, subjAlt, pubkey, keylength, serial, certvalidfrom, certvalidtill, issuerCN, sign, timestamp))
>   pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('Invalid parameter type.  param-index=1 param-type=X509Name', 'HY105')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [doc](https://www.pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html#OpenSSL.crypto.X509Req.get_subject) says that `X509Req`'s `get_subject()` method returns a `X509Name` object. This object can't be used as `Subject` field of your query; because they're Python objects and your MSSQL Server can't understand that.

Maybe you have designed this field to be a `VARCHAR` or something; so you need to use one of methods of that `X509Name` object to get the actual value you want to store (A string, maybe?) in your database. [Take a look at `X509Name`'s characteristics here](https://www.pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html#OpenSSL.crypto.X509Name).

Or you may want to convert the whole of this object into byte array using Python's [`pickle.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.dumps) method and [save it to your DB as binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518051/save-byte-array-in-sql-server).

Comment: Yes thank you! I figured out I have to give the params new string objects and now it works!