# Hash algorithm returning abnormal string length

Tags: c#, hash

I am hashing a string `3C970E3BF535` using the below method:

```
    internal static string Hash(string content)
    {
        System.Security.Cryptography.KeyedHashAlgorithm ha = System.Security.Cryptography.KeyedHashAlgorithm.Create();
        string asmKey = "Some key";
        byte[] hashkey = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(asmKey);
        byte[] data1 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(content);
        byte[] data2 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(content.ToLower());

        System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512 hmac = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512(hashkey);
        byte[] hashmac1 = hmac.ComputeHash(data1);
        byte[] hashmac2 = hmac.ComputeHash(data2);
        string hashmacencoded1 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(hashmac1);
        string hashmacencoded2 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(hashmac2);
        return string.Format("{0:X}", hashmacencoded1.GetHashCode());
    }
```

The output I get is `2BED23B1`. The length is `8`.

If I reverse the string, using this method:

```
    private static string Reverse(string s)
    {
        char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(charArray);
        return new string(charArray);
    }
```

And then re-hash it, I get 7 characters - `707D653` instead of 8 characters of the non-reversed hash, though the fact that it's reversed or non-reversed shouldn't matter at all, since hashing *should* return same length despite the input.

I have switched out the key that we actually use, so if you use the code above it would not reproduce the issue. The issue would ONLY pop up if we use our key. What is going on?

Comment: Why are you using the hash code of a *string representation* of the hash? (It's not even a good string representation - don't use Encoding.GetString to convert arbitrary binary data to text...)

Comment: GetHashCode doesn't mean what you seem to think it means...

Comment: And it's entirely clear what you're even trying to achieve, to be honest...

Comment: Hey Jon do you mind clarifying what you mean? Perhaps provide an example/solution below?

Comment: You're using cryptography framework to generate a hash of your content, as a string.  Then you're getting the hash of your hash.  That's almost certainly wrong.  You just want to use the hash as the hash, instead of double hashing it.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage try this `var str = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new byte[] { 63, 163 });` and see the content of str. What do you think is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString` to represent the hash because the hash is just a (pseudo) random assortment of bytes, not a binary representation of an ASCII string.

Instead you could represent it as a base64 string.

```
Convert.ToBase64String(hashmac1); // ABCDEF123== for example
```

You also should not be testing the `GetHashCode()` of the result - this is a different code that is used internally in the .NET framework for key-based data structures such as `Dictionary`, `HashSet`, etc. Just output the variable, not the hash code of the variable - the variable *is* the hash code.

Comment: If you have a specific problem I can certainly assist you, but I am not a code writing service.

Comment: I mean, @Matthew probably IS a code writing service, but he charges for said service like most other professional developers.

Comment: I'm not asking for code writing, but I can certainly see how it can appear I am. For that, I apologize. Are you suggesting, instead of using `byte[] data1 = ...`, to switch it out for something else?

Comment: Hash algorithms typically return byte arrays.  The problem is how you want to represent that byte array in string format (in which you attempted ASCII).  I suggest you use Base64 encoding to represent that binary as a string.  There are other ways to represent an arbitrary array of bytes, but by far I find base64 the easiest to work with.

Comment: Hi Matthew -- thanks for the insight. Can you suggest me a better algorithm to hash strings that return a length that can be controlled?

Comment: A Hash will always return the same length.  For instance, SHA512 will always return 512bits (64 bytes).

Comment: I will be using this person's suggestion: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4329927/1913389 What do you think? I am not using this method to store passwords -- only hashing some strings.

Answer (score 1):

The result of [`string.GetHashCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.gethashcode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is always a 32bit signed integer.

In this case, your result just happened to have a leading zero, which gets lopped off when you do `string.Format("{0:X}", ... )`

There are all sorts of other problems with this (why are you getting the hash code of the hash?) but that's the answer to the problem you actually asked about.