# Appropriate format to store password into SQL Server 2008?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am creating an ASP.Net website for first time and I want to store the password of login page into the database in any encoded format not directly as it is. But encryption and decryption should occur automatically.

Any suggestion for this ??

Comment: Passwords should be hashed, with salt - not encrypted.

Answer (score 3):

**De**cryption of the stored password should not be possible for security reasons. If the user tries to authenticate, "encrypt" the entered password again and compare it to the value in the database.

The mathematical method to do this is called a [**cryptographic hash function**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function). To protect against [rainbow table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) attacks, the hash should also be [salted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)).

---

If you want to implement this yourself, there are lots of questions here on SO on how to do this with .NET. Here are a few of them:

- [Hash and salt passwords in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2138429/87698)
- [How to salt and hash a password value using c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2005054/87698)
- [Hashing passwords with MD5 or sha-256 C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4329909/87698)

---

On the other hand, since you are using ASP.NET, you could make your life easier and just use the built-in ASP.NET membership provider, which [already does all the necessary security stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1137368/87698). Here's an MSDN article to get you started:

- [Introduction to Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy(VS.100).aspx)