# Hashing passwords for on-disk storage (More details inside)

Tags: security, passwords, hash

I need to store hashes of passwords on disk. I am not entirely sure which hash function to use (they all seem somewhat troubled at the moment), but I am leaning towards SHA-256.

My plan is to take the user's password and combine it with their user ID, a random user-specific salt, and a universal site-wide salt. Should I concatenate these values together and then hash the single resulting string, or should I hash each separately, concatenate the hashes, and then hash that? Also, does the order (password, user id, user salt, site salt) matter? Can I rearrange them however I like, or is it a bad idea to have something that doesn't change (site salt) or something completely predictable (user id/user salt) first?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SHA-256 seems to be one of the better options available right now.

Concatenating everything should be fine and order isn't all that important. Just make sure that you are using a significantly long salt value.

This post has some good recommendations-
[What algorithm should I use to hash passwords into my database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116684/what-algorithm-should-i-use-to-hash-passwords-into-my-database)

Answer (score 1):

Why not `bcrypt`?  Password hashing should be very slow, but SHA* is designed to be very fast.  `bcrypt` is specifically designed for password hashing.

Answer (score 0):

Previous SO questions about this:

[Password handling best practices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246463/password-handling-best-practices/1246560#1246560)

[What algorithm should I use to hash passwords into my database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116684/what-algorithm-should-i-use-to-hash-passwords-into-my-database)

But to provide brief answers to your specific questions:

- SHA-256 is a viable option.
- You can hash the single string.
- Order doesn't matter.
- You don't need two salts. Just a user-specific salt is fine, the site-wide one is unnecessary and doesn't actually contribute anything.

Comment: Grr - beat me by 18 Seconds. Sorry for the duplication :D

Comment: No worries - that's somewhat the nature of StackOverflow. :)

Answer (score 0):

Never hash hashes!!

Comment: Good question - I have no idea what I thinking at the time... Perhaps simply because if a hash is predictable, so is a hash of a hash - you still want to salt it.

Comment: You shouldn't re-hash a raw hash (without a salt) because it will expose