# What is a secure way to store a Paypal Pro Password? (PHP)

Tags: php, paypal

I'm setting up Paypal Pro and am considering ways to store my password securely.  This is Paypal's testing code and comments.  How should I change this in order to securely protect the password?

**I am only storing 1 password here - our API Password.**

```
/**
# API_password: The password associated with the API user
# If you are using your own API username, enter the API password that
# was generated by PayPal below
# IMPORTANT - HAVING YOUR API PASSWORD INCLUDED IN THE MANNER IS NOT
# SECURE, AND ITS ONLY BEING SHOWN THIS WAY FOR TESTING PURPOSES
*/

define('API_PASSWORD', 'LJKL235JL532K35');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most important thing is to store the password outside of your web-root folder.

Apart from that I don´t really see what else you can do; if people gain access to the folders where the scripts are stored, they also have access to the code that decrypts / retrieves the password so no matter how good the encryption is, the password will be available. Unless I´m missing something...

Comment: I think you're right - I don't think there's much else to do besides that.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at this previous question:

[Password handling best practices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246463/password-handling-best-practices)

Comment: This isn't a password for users, it's our api password - that's a good though

Answer (score 0):

Store it encrypted in your database, or in a file.  If you want a more specific answer, you'll have to ask a more specific question.

Comment: Only 1 password in question - our API password - store it in the database?

Comment: for single passwords store it in a file/encrypted, outside the webroot for maximum security.

Answer (score 0):

You may crypt the password, using a key that you know and don't store. I think you need to have mcrypt extension on in your PHP.
I have made a set of functions crypt/decrypt if you're interested.