# nodejs get the saved hash from the database

Tags: node.js

how can i get the value of the password field using the email provided or retrieved from the login

```
exports.Authenticate= async function (data){
    try {
            let sql = 'SELECT * FROM "'+config.DDTAA+'"."Users" WHERE "Email"= $1 AND "Password"= $2 AND "Status"=$3';
            const query = await pool.query(sql, [data.Email,data.Password,data.Status]);
            console.log(query)
            // callback - checkout a client
            return pool.query(sql, [data.Email, data.Password,data.Status])
            .then((res) => { return res;})
            .catch((err) => { return console.error('---Error executing query---\n', err.stack) });  
    } catch(err) { return console.error(err); } 
}
```

this is the result of **console.log(query)**

[image]

Comment: Sorry, it's not quite clear what you want to do. Do you want to know if the password from an auth request is the same as the one in the DB?

Comment: oh, sorry about that, i am not good in english. , yes thats right.

Comment: I just want to compare the login password to db password

Comment: ohh cool, yeah no problem. To compare the two, you need to compare their hashes. So you should hash the password in the request with the same algorithm used with the one in the DB.

Comment: take a look at this, for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116684/what-algorithm-should-i-use-to-hash-passwords-into-my-database

Comment: yes exactly !! can you please show me the solutions please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232355/discussion-between-germanio-and-user14823468).